# Impementation of Boolean function using decoders

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need help with implementation of this Boolean function:

```
F(A,B,C,D)=П(0,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,15), (conjunctive normal form)
```

with minimum number of decoders 2 to 4 and one NOR gate.

Using Shannon's expansion theorem with two levels of integration (without NOR gate):

[image]

My question is how to implement NOR gate with these decoders.
Thanks for replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are 4 input variables, we can have 16 input combinations possible. And each of these combinations are numbered, from 0 to 15. The function represented by

```
F(A,B,C,D)=П(0,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,15)
```

means that the output should be logical `0` for all the combinations listed in the bracket (maxterms). If the input combination does not belong to this list, then the output is `1`.

Using the 2-level arrangement of decoders you have obtained 16 output lines each corresponding to an input combination (1 out of the 16). One of these lines will be `1` according to the input. And for output to become `1` that input should not belong to the maxterm list.

In other words, the final output should be `1` if all the lines in the maxterm list are `0`'s. So connecting the lines corresponding to the maxterms (0,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,15) to a NOR gate will give you the output. A 9-input NOR gate is required for this purpose.